# How to install libav/avconv on Mac OS X or macOS 11?

Tags: macos, libav

OSX comes with a command line video conversion utility [avconvert](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/avconvert.1.html) but this tool provides limited functionality compared to the [avconv](https://libav.org/avconv.html) provided by [libav](https://libav.org/).

How can I install avconv on OS X (or macOS 11)?

Comment: With Homebrew: `brew install libav`.

Comment: now: `libav has been disabled because it is not maintained upstream!`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First grab the library:

```
 wget http://libav.org/releases/libav-10.1.tar.gz
# use http://libav.org/releases/libav-snapshot.tar.bz2 for the latest snapshot
tar -xvzf libav-10.1.tar.gz 
cd libav-10.1
```

Set up the dependencies with [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) (or other package managers such as [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)):

```
sudo port install yasm zlib bzip2 faac lame speex libogg libvorbis libtheora libvpx x264 XviD openjpeg15 opencore-amr freetype
```

Build libav:

```
./configure \
--extra-cflags=-I/opt/local/include --extra-ldflags=-L/opt/local/lib \
--enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid \
--enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb \
--enable-nonfree --enable-libfaac \
--enable-libmp3lame --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx \
--enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libfreetype --enable-doc --enable-gnutls --enable-shared

make && sudo make install
```

Then you can run `avconv`:

```
avconv -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 output.mp4
```

---

- `x264 +asm` seems to be required to get working `cpu-capabilities`, so if you don't get them (ie. `[libx264 @ 0x7fe66101a800] using cpu capabilities: none!`) run:

> sudo port upgrade --enforce-variants x264 +asm

You should get sth like: `[libx264 @ 0x7fc62401b600] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2 AVX`

Comment: On Mac OSX, dependencies installed via MacPorts and using pkg-config are not found until you set environment variable `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig'.  Also, for the fun of it, you may add, to `./configure`, options: `--extra-cflags=-I/opt/local/include --extra-ldflags=-L/opt/local/lib`.  Then the whole `./configure` above miraculously passes!

Comment: brew install libav

Comment: On the second to last step, build lib-av. ERROR: gnutls not found

Comment: @ChaseRoberts Hi Chase, i also have the same problem with gnutls not found.  I tried following a guide https://gist.github.com/morgant/1753095 but encountered more errors.  Were you ever able to get things to work?

Comment: ok I just had to re-install homebrew in order to get `brew install libav` to work.

Answer (score 82):

Just install it with brew:

```
brew install libav
```

Comment: Ugh, why brew install avconv doesn't work is beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

For those without `brew` - and until macports come up with a port for `libav`, here are my notes for installing libav on OSX 10.8.5 from **source** (libav version `12_dev0`, from github).

The main problem I faced was that libav uses `sem_timedwait()` (semaphore.h in linux) which is not defined in macos.

This post https://stackoverflow.com/a/15163760 mentions that Keith Shortridge of the Australian Astronomical Observatory's software group (thanks) have written an implementation of said function for macos which can be found here https://github.com/attie/libxbee3/tree/master/xsys_darwin

Download the two files into `${LIBAVDIR}/libavdevice` and then add the following line in the header file `sem_timedwait.h`:

`int sem_timedwait(sem_t *sem, const struct timespec *abs_timeout);`

Then edit the Makefile in `${LIBAVDIR}/libavdevice` and add `sem_timedwait.o` at the end of the `OBJS` variable

configure 
and make all

you are good to go.

for the record, I used the following configure command:

`./configure --extra-cflags=-I/opt/local/include --extra-ldflags=-L/opt/local/lib --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-nonfree --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libfreetype --enable-doc --enable-gnutls --prefix=/opt/local`

**WARNING: I can not say or guarantee whether the said implementation of `sem_timedwait()` is the correct one and/or will have no side-effects to the working of `libav` or indeed any other part of the system which links to libav libraries which have now a `sem_timedwait()` implementation in there!!!! For the latter may I suggest renaming `sem_timedwait()` everywhere in your copy of `libav` and Keith's implementation. Also check if any other symbols are exported from sem_timedwait.o and rename them also.**

Here are the new, renamed symbols from Keith Shortridge's implementation of `sem_timedwait()`:

`sem_timedwait_keith, timeoutThreadMain_keith, triggerSignal_keith, ignoreSignal_keith, timeoutThreadCleanup_keith`

(remove `_keith` to get the original names). The only reference to `sem_timedwait()` in `libav` (for said version) is in `jack.c`.

Answer (score 1):

For videos hosted on https (many, these days), make sure you build avconv with OpenSSL support:

```
brew install libav --with-openssl
```